# How to open pdf in new tab oracle apex 20.2

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.1

I can successfully upload, download pdf files in **blob column** but I want it to be open in **new tab**, it opens on same tab.
Column properties
**Type : Download BLOB,
Content Disposition : Inline**